# Web scraping Selenium Error: "with AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_class_name' "

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am very new to web scraping and just learned it today. I am trying to get data about current stocks yet I get a weird error. Any help?
Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\Heage\Coding\Python\Selenium\WebScraping\Popular TV
> Shows\main.py", line 17, in 
> company = companies.find_element_by_class_name("tv-data-table__row tv-data-table__stroke tv-screener-table__result-row") AttributeError:
> 'list' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_class_name'

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/markets/stocks-usa/market-movers-active/")

try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "js-screener-container")))
    companies = main.find_elements_by_class_name("tv-data-table__tbody")
    for company in companies:
        company = companies.find_element_by_class_name("tv-data-table__row tv-data-table__stroke tv-screener-table__result-row")
        for companyInfo in company:
            companyInfo = company.find_element_by_class_name("tv-data-table__cell apply-common-tooltip tv-screener-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell--left tv-screener-table__cell--big tv-screener-table__cell--with-marker")
            for companyInfoMore in companyInfo:
                companyInfoMore = companyInfo.find_element_by_class_name("tv-screener-table__symbol-container ")
                for companyTitle in companyInfoMore:
                    companyTitle = companyInfoMore.find_element_by_class_name("tv-screener__symbol apply-common-tooltip")
                    print(companyTitle)
            for companyChangePercent in companyInfo:
                companyChangePercent = companyInfo.find_element_by_class_name("tv-data-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell--up tv-screener-table__cell--big tv-screener-table__cell--with-marker")
                print(companyChangePercent)

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by Nikita has an explanation why your code produces this error.
But the current implementation is very wrong.

1 You use multiple for loops. You do not need this

2 You use `find_element_by_class_name` for multiple class names. But this is not supported. You have to use either `XPath` or `css` selectors for multiple class names.

3 You are waiting like this: `main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until( EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "js-screener-container")))`
But it will unlikely wait for the table contents.

4 You are waiting for elements to be present, but it is more reliable to wait till they are visible

Answering your main question:  `'list' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_class_name'` means that you are calling `find_element_by_class_name` method from list, which does not have it. You should use it like this:

```
driver. find_element_by_class_name("some_class")
```

I've started your code, so it would be easier for you to understand how the code really should looks like.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/markets/stocks-usa/market-movers-active/")


main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".tv-data-table__tbody .tv-data-table__row.tv-data-table__stroke.tv-screener-table__result-row")))
companies = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".tv-data-table__tbody .tv-data-table__row.tv-data-table__stroke.tv-screener-table__result-row")
result = []
for company in companies:
    name_short = company.find_element_by_css_selector(".tv-screener__symbol.apply-common-tooltip").text
    name_long = company.find_element_by_css_selector(".tv-screener__description").text
    last = company.find_element_by_css_selector(".tv-data-table__cell.tv-screener-table__cell.tv-screener-table__cell--big.tv-screener-table__cell--with-marker:nth-of-type(2)>span").text
    result.append([name_short, name_long, last])
for p in result:
    print(p, sep='\n')
```

First 5 lines of the output:

```
['GERN', 'GERON CORPORATION', '1.83']
['AMC', 'AMC ENTERTAINMENT HOLDINGS, INC.', '59.26']
['XLF', 'SPDR SELECT SECTOR FUND - FINANCIAL ETF', '35.23']
['WISH', 'CONTEXTLOGIC INC.', '11.40']
['SNDL', 'SUNDIAL GROWERS INC.', '0.9230']
```

Some hints:

- Learn locators, specifically XPATH and CSS
- Learn how to work with lists
- Go through this tutorial to understand Selenium better https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/
- Avoid multiple inner loops as much as you can. Otherwise your programs will be very slow and difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

```
company = companies.find_element_by_class_name("tv-data-table__row tv-data-table__stroke tv-screener-table__result-row")
```

Have a look at this line. companies(note it is in plural form) is defined from find_element**s**_by_class_name whose return value is list. Thus, companies is a list and it doesn't have such an attribute.

Guess it can be like this.

```
company = company.find_element_by_class_name("tv-data-table__row tv-data-table__stroke tv-screener-table__result-row")
```

This assigns a new element to company. And it has method - find_element_by_class_name